# Inject WebSocket in service REST

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, websocket, scope

I need to send a message a client, after the creation of item. The item is created an ApiRest. Then I created my WebSocket with @ApplicationScope and I Injected in serviceREST with @Inject. The Problem is when the webSocket was initialized, in my serviceRest this webSocket's session still is null.
How I can use the web SOcket in my apirest?

```
@Path("citas")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class citaResource {

    @Inject
    com.softcase.citasmanager.websocket.ws websocket;

    @GET
    @Path("cita")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response cita() {
       websocket.onMessage("Your Item was created");//Session of webSocket is null
        return Response.ok("ItemCreated", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}

@ApplicationScope
@ServerEndpoint("/item")
public class ws{   

    private Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
            this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }
```

Comment: I think you are wrongly mixing websocket and REST. They are two different protocols to send information from a client to a server or vice-versa. It's like to do Paris-New York, you can take a boat or a plane. You are basically asking a passenger who bought a boat round trip ticket to go to New York by boat but coming back by plane. On a more serious note, one instance of `ServerEndpoint`, in Tyrus implementation, is created per client. How you can identify which client REST is currently talking to?

Comment: But I supossed that when I injected a webSocket with ApplicationScoped, I will have the webSocket with the updated data(In case that a session has been created, before Injected), because when it is ApplicationScoped I have only one instance.

Comment: You can check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500388/4906586). Basically, I prefer to have a dedicated `@ApplicationScope` which list all existing `@ServerEndpoint`

Comment: In terms of code, how do I do that?

Comment: I can try writing an answer for that but I need to know how you identify the websocket sessions you are trying to reach. Let's assume there are user A, B, C etc... A is sending a request to the `citas` path and received the `ItemCreated`. Let's assume A, B, C ... have their websocket sessions opened. Who will received the websocket message? and how you identify A, B, C ... ? with username? email?

Comment: But the problem is that the object websocket.session is null!Even when I already opened the session, from any other client!
 It does not matter to identify the session, because I send the message to all the webSocket sessions.

Comment: As all the explanation is a bit long, I posted it as an answer. Please let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: does the answer fit your question or is there anything unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A little context

> **Instances**: there is a unique Session instance per client-server pair i.e. one instance of Session is created for a each client which connects to the WebSocket server endpoint. In short, the number of unique Session instances is equal to number of connected clients

<sub>Source: https://abhirockzz.gitbooks.io/java-websocket-api-handbook/content/lifecycle_and_concurrency_semantics.html</sub>

<sub>For more details: https://tyrus-project.github.io/documentation/1.13.1/index/lifecycle.html</sub>

A suggestion is to use a `static` variables like

```java
// @ApplicationScope
@ServerEndpoint("/item")
public class ws{   
    // something like
    private static final Set<javax.websocket.Session> ALL_SESSIONS = new HashSet<>();

    // ...
}
```

An example can be found [here](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2017/04/27/handling-state-in-java-websocket-applications/#gist46709615). It's an option but I do not think it solves your injection issue.

Another option is to leverage the [`javax.websocket.Session#getOpenedSessions()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#getOpenSessions--) method such as this [chat example](http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/java-websocket-api-fetch-all-websocket.html). But once again, it does not solve the injection issue.

### Your example

You are using both websocket and REST. As I understand, the flow is:

1. User A, B, C are connected
2. User A submits a request to `citas/cita` and receives the REST response
3. At the same time, A, B, C receive a websocket notification

So, as you wrote, on one hand, you have

```java
@Path("citas")
// ...
public class CitaResource{
    // ...
}
```

and

```java
// @ApplicationScope -> commented as irrelevant in your situation
@ServerEndpoint("/item")
public class ws{   
    // ...
}
```

In the example, there is one instance of `CitaResource` when user A made the request and three instances of `ws` as A, B, C are connected. However, you were right about the injection: you need to have something injected in `CitaResource` but you need a bean that is always available and as you noticed, websocket instances are not a good option and which session the container must inject?

### A websocket sessions handler

The solution is to use an application scoped bean to handle all the existing sessions. I got it from [Oracle tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#section5). It goes like this:

```java
// com.softcase.citasmanager.websocket.SessionHandler
@ApplicatedScoped
@Named // optional
public class MySessionHandler{

    private final Set<Session> ALL_SESSIONS;
    // or use a map if you need to identify the
    // the session by a key. This example uses Set
    // private final Map<String, Session> ALL_SESSIONS;

    public MySessionHandler(){
        ALL_SESSIONS = new HashSet<>();
    }

    // manage sessions
    public void addSession(Session session){
        this.ALL_SESSIONS.add(session);
    }

    public void removeSession(Session session){
        this.ALL_SESSIONS.remove(session);
    }

    // send messages to all instances:
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        this.ALL_SESSIONS.stream()
            // optional
            .filter(s -> s.isOpen())
            // or whatever method you want to send a message
            .forEach( s -> s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }
    // or if you want to target a specific session
    // hence my questions in comments
    public void sendMessage(String message, String target){
        this.ALL_SESSIONS..stream()
            // identity the target session
            .filter(s -> s.equals(target))
            // optional
            .filter(s -> s.isOpen())
            .forEach( s -> s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }

}
```

Note:

- I optionally check that the stored session is still opened. [`isOpen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#isOpen--) is not mandatory but it might avoid some errors
- Think the session handler as the "captain": it knows everything about the websocket sessions whereas the sessions themselves do not know about each other.

However, you need to adapt your endpoint to make the session handler efficient:

```java
// com.softcase.citasmanager.websocket.WsCita
@ServerEndpoint
public class WsCita{

    // there is no need to declare the session as attribute
    // private Session session;

    // ApplicatedScoped so always defined
    @Inject
    private MySessionHandler handler;

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session){
        handler.addSession(session);    // "Aye cap'tain, reporting from duty!"
        // your stuff
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session, CloseReason closeReason){
        handler.removeSession(session); // "Cya cap'tain, that's all for today!"
        // your stuff
    }

    // your OnMessage and other stuff here
}
```

Now we have set our websocket architecture, what now?

1. You have one instance of `WsCita` per client. At any time, there might be zero, one or more instances.
2. `MySessionHandler` knows this information and is `@ApplicatedScoped` so it is safe to inject it

The REST endpoint then changes to:

```
@Path("citas")
// ...
public class citaResource {

    @Inject
    com.softcase.citasmanager.websocket.SessionHandler handler;

    @GET
    // ...
    public Response cita() {
        // REST processing
        // ...

        // Websocket processing:
        // - Handler is always here for you
        // - Handler knows which websocket sessions to send the message to.
        //   The RestController is not aware of the recipients
        handler.sendMessage("Your Item was created");
    }

}
```

Please note that I put the websocket processing after the REST processing as you may not always send the message (e.g. creation or whatever exception).

### Misc

Unrelated to your questions but I have some comments about your code:

- Classes name are CamelCase starting with capitalized letter [per Oracle recommendation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
- Avoid generic name for your classes such as `Ws`. I renamed it `WsCita` for the example